# Drawing line to the nearest point following a attribute hierarchy

Tags: qgis, line, geometry-generator, closest-distance

With a point layer and a attribute table formed by the field "HIERACHY", where there are 3 values (3,2,1). The meaning of the values is from highest to lowest relevance in descending order: 1 highest relevance, 2 intermediate relevance and 3 lowest relevance:

[image]

I would like to draw the lines to the nearest point following the hierarchy order. I show a simulation of what it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your follow up question about connecting the points based on an alphabetic instead a numerical hierarchy, there are at least two principal ways to do that, depending if you have only one character (`'A'`) or a text string consisting of several characters (`'Anna'`).

#### Alphabetical order consisting of just one letter

The easiest is if you have just one letter (`'A'`, `'B'` etc.). Convert this letter to it's ASCII code using [`ascii()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#ascii) function, then you have a number and you can proceed as in the other solution. Simply replace `hierarchy` on lines 3 and 10 with `ascii(hierarchy)` and you're done.

#### Alphabetical order from text strings with several characters

If you have whole text string attributes (`'Anna'`, `'Berta'` etc.) for the points an want to connect them alphabetically, it's a bit more complicated and you have to use another approach as follows below.

*Screenshot: each point is connected to the closest point with the next value alphabetically; so `Berta` is alway connected to the closest `Cleopatra`, even if a `Diana` or `Anna` is closer:*
[image]

1. Create a new attribute that for each feature creates the next alphabetical entry. To do so, aggregate all `hierarchy` values in an array ([`array_agg()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-agg)), reduce it to unique values ([`array_distinct()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-distinct)) and sort it alphabetically ([`array_sort()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-sort)). Then identify the position (index) of the current `hierarchy` value in this array ([`array_find()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-find)) and get the next (index+1) value in the array ([`array_get()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-get)). Use this expression with field calculator to create the field named `next`:

   ```
    with_variable(
        'distinct',
        array_sort (array_distinct (array_agg (hierarchy))),
        array_get (@distinct, array_find (@distinct, hierarchy) +1)
    )
   ```
2. Draw the lines with the following expression. Be sure to include all single quotes with two `''` and three `'''` repetitions exactly as in the expression to work correctly:

   ```
    with_variable(
        'next',
        next, 
        eval('
            make_line(
                $geometry,
                overlay_nearest(
                    ''point'',
                    $geometry,
                    filter:= hierarchy = ''' || @next || '''
                )[0]
            )
        ')
    )
   ```

Comment: Always learning and expanding knowledge of complete and clarifying answers. And also surprised by the possibilities of QGIS. I suppose there are limitations but it seems that with genius and creativity, any idea is possible to materialise

Comment: Could you share a little explanation of how to get the Arrow effect? It seems that in the expression you add the function "line_substring(@ll,0,length(@ll)*0.98)" to modify the size of the Head arrow depending on the length.
It is quite interesting to show this effect

Comment: As a detailed description would be too long here, I posted this as a separate question/answer - see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/460323/88814

Answer (score 8):

Use this expression:

```
with_variable(
    'curr',
    hierarchy,
    make_line (
        $geometry, 
        eval(
            'overlay_nearest(
                ''point'',
                $geometry,
                filter:=hierarchy-1='  || @curr  || 
            ')'
        )[0]
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to adapt the structure of this same expression to work with string fields (Z to A) and have the possibility to sort in ascending or descending order?

Comment: I added another answer to address this.