# Creating arrow effect using QGIS geometry generator

Tags: qgis, line, expression, geometry-generator

In [another answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460262/88814), there was a QGIS screenshot posted that shows lines created by geometry generator, connecting points in a hierarchical order. As a follow up question ([see comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460155/drawing-line-to-the-nearest-point-following-a-attribute-hierarchy/460262?noredirect=1#comment751787_460262)): Could you explain how to get this arrow effect?

What can be seen in the screenshot is that you used the expression `line_substring(@ll,0,length(@ll)*0.98)` to modify the length of the line:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can download the project + data used to create the screenshot from here: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/6hj4F3EO9NCxuds so you can inspect the details, based on the following description, and try to tweak the values yourself.*

##### Reducing line's length

The expression you see in the screenshot is creating a variable `@ll` that stores the line connecting the points in the hierarchical order (as [described in the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460262/88814)) and then based on this uses the function `line_substring()` to shorten the line a bit. In fact, the expression `line_substring(@ll,0,length(@ll)*0.98)` returns 98% length of the input line. This is to get a small gap between the top of the arrow and the point. Like this, differnt arrow heads and points do not overlap too much.

##### Styling the line/arrow with date driven override

I then used several data driven overrides in layer styling panel to style the arrows differently: arrow widht, head length, head thickness and fill color. For this, I used the [Assistant](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#data-defined-assistant) (see next screenshot). As `Source`, use any attribute or expression that gives you a range of numbers - in this specific case, I used ([based on the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460262/88814)) the expression `array_find (array_sort(array_distinct (array_agg(hierarchy))),hierarchy)`.

Then load or manually define values `from/to` for the possible range of the output of this expression and finally set a value output `from/to`: in the screenshot, the smallest arrow head has a size of 2, the largest a size of 10. In a similar way, I defined values for the other style elements. You can check it in detail in the project linked above.

[image]